# JS Open new window and close new window after N seconds

Tags: javascript, window

I want to open a new window using javascript(`window.open("some_url")`) and after some time i want to close that window. Is this possible using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the window, then use `setTimeout` to close after some interval.

```
var newWindow = window.open("some_url");
setTimeout(() => newWindow.close(), 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Try `setTimeout` for this task:

```
const windowGoogle = window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');

//This will close google's window after 3000 miliseconds
setTimeout(() => {
  windowGoogle.close()
}, 3000)
```

Comment: Is it right to remove "() => "? I'm sorry but I I don't understand what this code does.